# How to update Qt version that qmake uses?

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to use qmake with QT 5.7.0 or later. I have installed QT 5.7.0. I have never installed another version of QT before or after this. When I run
    qmake --version

it tells me it is using Qt 5.5.1. I don't know how it gets to this version, this version was never installed by me. I would like to update the version that qmake uses. How can I do that?

Comment: have a look at here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/how-do-i-change-which-version-of-qt-is-used-for-qmake/233982

Comment: Thank you, one of the unaccepted answers helped!